# Getting constant value from asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, react-native

Here is my code.

```
const fbLoginData= {}

function _responseInfoCallbackID (error, result) {
  if (error) {
    fbLoginData.error="Unable to fetch data.Try again later or use other methods to sign-in"
  } 
  else {
    fbLoginData.id = result.id
    fbLoginData.email=result.email
    fbLoginData.name=result.name
    }
}

function _responseInfoCallbackPicture (error, result) {
  if (error) {
    fbLoginData.error="Unable to fetch data.Try again later or use other methods to sign-in"
  } 
  else {
    fbLoginData.profile= result.data.url
    }
}

export async function logInFB () {

    try{
      const login = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(["public_profile","email"])
      const value = await getValue(login)
      console.warn(" THE VALUE I AM SENDING ",value)
      return value
    }

    catch(error)
    {
      fbLoginData.error= "Unable to fetch Data"
    }
  }



const getValue = (result)=> {
  if (!result.isCancelled) {
    return AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
      (data) => {

        fbLoginData.accessToken = data.accessToken

        const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
          '/me',
          {
            accessToken,
            parameters: {
              fields: {
                string: 'email,name'
              }
            }
          },
          _responseInfoCallbackID,
        );

        const pictureRequest = new GraphRequest(
          `/me/${PICTURE_PARAM}`,
          {
            accessToken,        
          },
          _responseInfoCallbackPicture,
        );

        // Start the graph request.
        new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start()
        new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(pictureRequest).start()
        return  fbLoginData
      }
    )
  } 
}
```

I want to have fbLoginData object to be filled with the data after having the callback functions `_responseInfoCallbackID` and `_responseInfoCallbackPicture` called. But the async function loginFB value doesn't return any other data than access token, but I want id, email, name that gets returned. I know the problem is due to asynchronicity, how can I get the fbLoginData with all the data I need? I cannot figure out the way I can do that. Any help on how to get the loginFB return the fbLoginData value with id,email,name and image that I want ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by following below steps:

1. Wrap the graph request's 
          `new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(callback).start()`  inside  a promise block
2. Create a global object `promiseContainer`and add the resolve and reject method of the above created promises to it.
3. Pass the above promises to Promise.all.
4. Resolve the promise inside of the `callback` function by using `promiseContainer`.

The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises passed as an iterable have resolved or when the iterable contains no promises.

```js
const fbLoginData = {};
const promiseContainer = {};

function _responseInfoCallbackID(error, result) {
  
    // Earlier Code

  promiseContainer.infoPromise.resolve(true);
}

function _responseInfoCallbackPicture(error, result) {
  
    // Earlier Code

  promiseContainer.picturePromise.resolve(true);
}

// Earlier Code

const getValue = result => {
  if (!result.isCancelled) {
    return AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(data => {
      
        // Earlier code

      const infoPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        promiseContainer['infoPromise'] = { resolve, reject };
        new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
      });

      const picturePromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        promiseContainer['picturePromise'] = { resolve, reject };
        new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(pictureRequest).start();
      });
      return Promise.all([infoPromise, picturePromise]).then(() => fbLoginData);
    });
  }
};
```